# Chrome - eval - function()

Tags: function, google-chrome, eval

Why is Chrome throwing

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

when i try to call:

```
eval("function(){alert('test')}")
```

?

Comment: why do you want to define an anonymous function that never gets used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome is throwing the SyntaxError because you either need () around your function or you need to name it.

```
//This defines a as the function
eval("function a(){alert('foo')}");

//This returns the anonymous function
eval("(function(){alert('foo')})");
```

either should work properly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you (second option is what i was looking for) - do you know if this will be supported by all browsers ?

Comment: "need () around your function or you need to name it" --- but WHY?

Comment: landon9720 -- If you don't name the function you cannot execute it, as it will be an anonymous function you can never find again. by putting the () around it, or better () around followed by () you will execute the function.

Comment: Mimisbrunnr: One could execute it via `eval("function (){alert('foo')}")();`. Or, much more likely, by saving the result of eval and retrieving & applying it later. It's very useful to construct functions and apply them later.

Comment: Mimisbrunnr: How did you learn of Chrome's requirement for outer parens in this special case?

Comment: @Conal -- Honestly I don't remember anymore it has been too long since I did.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, Safari 5.1 and Chrome 13.0.782.220 do require outer parens in this special case of anonymous functions. I have no idea why, as the expression is no more ambiguous or less useful without the parens than with. Firefox 6.0.2 is perfectly happy without the parens.

Does anyone know whether the Javascript language spec specifies these outer parens and whether they're necessary for cases other than anonymous functions?